# Is lazier (ksh-like) function autoloading possible in bash?

Tags: bash, function, autoload

My project (port from ksh) use some directories as autoloadable functions.
In those directories each filenames as the name of a function declared inside the file, sourcing that file to declare (implement) the function. Each directories could be considered a 'package' that augment the bash builtin set via functions. I have about 20 packages, and the number of functions per package can be significant (can reach 30 in some packages).

---

The bash documentation includes an example implementation of autoloading:

https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/main/all/bash-doc/4.3-6ubuntu1/file/usr/share/doc/bash/examples/functions/autoload.v2

However, that implementation requires the set of potentially-autoloadable functions to be known (and enumerated) at shell startup time.

Is an implementation that doesn't have that limitation possible?

Comment: Ouch, apologies for the irrelevant part about future,  I misred it and thought for a moment that this was a kind of preview of a coming feature. Glad you find it simple, and didn't spot at first that code was from the bash author. Didn't want to upset anybody :-) Cheers.

Comment: I am not an expert at stackoverflow, so I don't really understand if the reopen and reformulate would remove all the previous comment. If so may be I should simply drop the 'wronlgy formulated' part and keep only the 'good' one if good enough. I left both because the above comment would have no sense if they still exist after the reopen with the 'wrong' part removed.

Comment: I've tried to trim this down a little further; think it's a good candidate for reopening now. As a hint on where to start, `command_not_found_handle` seems like a reasonable place to implement something of this sort.

Comment: By the way, for future note -- it's fine for edits to invalidate comments; it's edits that invalidate *answers* that are frowned on.

Comment: I do not understand this. You want to do like `func() { source dir/func; func "$@"; }; func`? How does ksh autoload work?

Comment: Thanx @charles for managing the post I I.e editing etc... I didn't know about command_not_found_handle. I'll take a look tomorrow. Thanx for this pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after asking, my turn to 'give' :) to the SO community. I investigated this auto load feature I need and came up with 2 implementations, I provide one them here, so some may suggest enhancements or point out bugs. I'll post the second one on a second post.

The 2 implementations will runs some test cases, so before presenting the implementations I present the common test cases. We have 2 directories a1/ and a2/ that host function definitions located in file with same name as the function, each dir could be considered a 'package' dir containing functions for this package, and then function in there are namespaced with the package name (dir name), with few exception for the test purpose.

```
./a1/ac_f3::
function ac_f3
{ echo "In a1 ac_f3() : args=$@"
}

./a1/a1_f1::
function a1_f1
{ echo "In a1_f1() : args=$@"
}


./a1/a1_f2::
function a1_f22
{ echo "In a1_f2() : args=$@"
}


./a2/ac_f3::
function f3
{ echo "In a2 ac_f3() : args=$@"
}

./a2/a2_f1::
function a2_f1
{ echo "In a2_f1() : args=$@"
}
```

ac_f3 is a function that is not namespaced, and then common to both dir a1/ a2/ yet with different implementation, this is to demonstrate the $FPATH precedence.

a1_f2 is a bogus one it doesn't implement the function a1_f2() and then we must fail gracefully.

a1_f1, a2_f1, simply implement a1_f1() a2_f2(), and must be found and executed.

**command_not_found_handle implementation**

Thanks Charles for bringing the command_not_found_handle option, because, surely auto loadable function are related to the fact that a 'command' has not been found and then we try to find a auto loadable to load and execute.

But amazingly, the bash shell has an interesting "feature", i.e some undocumented behavior.

Bash doc says.

```
   If the search is unsuccessful, the shell searches for a defined
   shell function named command_not_found_handle.  If that
   function exists, it is invoked with the original command and
   the original command's arguments as its arguments, and the
   function's exit status becomes the exit status of the shell.
   If that function is not defined, the shell prints an error
   message and returns an exit status of 127.
```

This is misleading because here we talk about the command_not_found_handle() function invocation, and then we may infere 'from the shell context' and this is not the case.

In the shell logic, we failed to get an alias, then fail to get a function, then failed to get an 'external to the shell' program, and the shell is already in a sub-shell creation mode, so command_not_found_handle() is invoked but in a subshell. not the shell context. This could be OK, but the 'funny feature' here is that the sub-process created is not clean, its $$ and $PPID are not set correctly, may be this will be fixed one day. To exhibit this bash feature we can do

```
function command_not_found_handle
{ echo $$ ; sh -c 'echo $PPID'
}

PW$ # In a shell context invocation    
PW$  command_not_found_handle
2746
2746

PW$ # In a subshell invocation (via command not found)    
PW$ qqq
2746
3090
```

Back to our autoload feature, this mean we want to install more functions in a shell instance, nothing that can be done in a subshell, so basically command_not_found_handle() is of tiny help and can do nothing beside signal its parent we got entered (then a command was not found), we will exploit this feature in our implementation.

```
# autoload
# This file must be sourced
# - From your rc files if you need autoloadable fuctions from your
#   interactive shell
# - From any script that need autoloadable functions.
#
# The FPATH must be set with a set of dirs/ where to look to find
# file name match the function name to source and execute.
#
# Note that if FPATH is exported, this is a way to export functions to
# script subshells

# Create a default command_not_found_handle if none exist
declare -F command_not_found_handle >/dev/null ||
function command_not_found_handle { ! echo bash: $1 command not found>&2; }

# Rename current command_not_found_handle
_cnf_body=$(declare -f command_not_found_handle | tail -n +2)
eval "function _cnf_prev $_cnf_body"

# Change USR1 to your liking
CNF_SIG=USR1

function autoload
{ declare f=$1 ; shift
  declare d s
  for d in $(IFS=:; echo $FPATH)
  do s=$d/$f
    [ -f $s -a -r $s ] &&
    { . $s
      declare -F $f >/dev/null ||
      { echo "$s exist but don't define $f" >&2 ; return 127
      }
      $f "$@" ; return
    }
  done
  _cnf_prev $f "$@"
}

trap 'autoload ${BASH_COMMAND[@]}' $CNF_SIG
function command_not_found_handle
{ kill -$CNF_SIG $$
}
```

WARNING, if you ever use this 'autoload' file be prepared for bash fix, it may one day reflect the real $$ $PPID, in which case you will need to fix the above snippet with 
**$PPID** instead of **$$**.

Results.

```
PW$ . /path/to/autoload
PW$ FPATH=a1:a2

PW$ a1_f1 11a 11b 11c
In a1_f1() : args=11a 11b 11c

PW$ a2_f1 21a 21b 21c
In a2_f1() : args=21a 21b 21c

PW$ a1_f2 12a 12b 12c
a1/a1_f2 exist but don't define a1_f2

PW$ ac_f3 c3a c3b c3c
In a1 ac_f3() : args=c3a c3b c3c

PW$ qqq  
Command 'qqq' not found, did you mean:

  command 'qrq' from snap qrq (0.3.1)
  command 'qrq' from deb qrq

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

What we got here is correct, a1_f1() a2_f1() are found, loaded, executed.

a1_f2() is nowhere to be found, despite having a file that could host it.

The qqq invocation  display the chaining of the handlers, going function autoload fist, then the ubuntu command-not-found package (if installed) meaning we are not loosing the command_not_found_handle() user experience.

Note there is no 'admin' functions here like adding/removing/reloading functions.

Adding is a matter of setting file in dirs present in $FPATH

Removing is a matter of removing the source file and unset -f the function

Reloading is a matter of editing the source file and unset -f the function.

Reloading function can be pretty neat during development in interactive shell, but all this can be done with a simple 
 `unset -f funcname`, so basically you edit your source file. unset the function, then call it, you get the latest. Same may happen in a script daemon, one could implement a signal to the daemon and the trap handler would simply unset a set of functions that would then be reloaded without stopping/restarting the daemon.

Another feature here is that shell 'package' are possible, i.e a source file may implement 'many' functions, some are the external API, other are internal to the package, since all is flat in the shell, function are namespaced, and then each external API functions (albeit documented) can be hard linked to the same file. The first external API used will load all the package functions.

In my project, the documentation is extracted from the packages sources, and then hardlink are inferred and build at this time.

**PROs and CONs**

**PROs**
Here we got a light signature in the autoload sourcing, i.e from scripts or from bash rc file (interactive), the define of the autoload() is modest.

It is very dynamic, in the sense that function loading and executing is really deferred until really needed.

**CONs**
It grabs a signal number, that would not be necessary should the command_not_found_handle() be a real function called from the shell context, this could happen one day.

It is implemented on a bash feature that may move (wrong, $$ $PPID) then need maintenance on the moving target.

**Conclusion**
This implementation is OK for me (I Don't care loosing SIGUSR1). The ideal solution would be that command_not_found_handle() would be cleanly implemented and then called in the shell context. The a similar implementation would be possible without any signal.

Answer (score 2):

This is a second implementation to avoid the signal usage seen in the previous implementation and the usage of the command_not_found_handle() that seems not completly stable.

```
autoload::
function autoload
{ local d="$1" && [ "$1" ] && shift && autoload "$@"  
  local identifier='^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$'
  [ -d "$d"  -a -x "$d" ] && cd "$d" &&
  { for f in *
    do [[ $f =~ $identifier ]] && alias $f=". $PWD/$f;unalias $f;$f"
    done
    cd ->/dev/null 2>&1
  }
}


autoload $@  $(IFS=:; echo $FPATH)
```

Here again we got to source this autolaod file either in rc file or in scripts.

The usage of FPATH is not really needed (see Notes for more details on FPATH)

So basically the idea is to source the autoload file along with a set of directories to look for.

```
PW$ . /path/to/autoload a1 a2
PW$ alias | grep 'a[12c]_*'
alias a1_f1='. /home/phi/a1/a1_f1;unalias a1_f1;a1_f1'
alias a1_f2='. /home/phi/a1/a1_f2;unalias a1_f2;a1_f2'
alias a2_f1='. /home/phi/a2/a2_f1;unalias a2_f1;a2_f1'
alias ac_f3='. /home/phi/a1/ac_f3;unalias ac_f3;ac_f3'

PW$ declare -F |  grep 'a[12c]_*'
```

After the autoload sourcing, we got all the alias defined and no functions.

This is a bit heavier than the previous implementation, yet pretty lightweight, alias are not costly to create in the shell, even with hundred of them.

```
PW$ a1_f1 11a 11b 11c
In a1_f1() : args=11a 11b 11c

PW$ a2_f1 21a 21b 21c
In a2_f1() : args=21a 21b 21c

PW$ alias | grep 'a[12c]_*'
alias a1_f2='. /home/phi/a1/a1_f2;unalias a1_f2;a1_f2'
alias ac_f3='. /home/phi/a1/ac_f3;unalias ac_f3;ac_f3'
PW$ declare -F |  grep 'a[12c]_*'

declare -f a1_f1
declare -f a2_f1
```

Here we see that a1_f1() and a2_f2() are then loaded and executed, they are removed from the alias list and added in the function list.

```
PW$ a1_f2 12a 12b 12c
a1_f2: command not found

PW$ ac_f3 c3a c3b c3c
In a1 ac_f3() : args=c3a c3b c3c

PW$ qqq 

Command 'qqq' not found, did you mean:

  command 'qrq' from snap qrq (0.3.1)
  command 'qrq' from deb qrq

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

Here we see that a1_f2() is not found, not well reported as in the previous implementation.

ac_f3() is the one from a1/ as expected.

qqq still provide the command-not-found distro package result if installed ( normal we didn't mess with command_not_found_handle() )

**PROs and CONs**

**PROs**
Not sitting on a bash bug, i.e could live for a while after bash updates.

**CONs**
A little bit heavier than previous implementation, yet acceptable.

Much simpler, well may be not simpler, but surely shorter than proposed examples in bash documentation, and a bit more lazy, i.e function are loaded only when necessary (not the aliases though)

Multi function 'package' files along with hardlink for external API exposure is less performing, because each external API function (hardlink) will trig a reload of the file, unless the package file is well written removing all the excess aliases after loading.